# How can I generate AWS SNS alert to trigger MS Teams notification when an object fails to load?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud, microsoft-teams, amazon-sns

I am trying to generate an SNS alert for MS Teams, and anytime I try to execute the function in Lambda I get the following error...
[ERROR] InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: Subject Traceback

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong or what I can change to generate an MS Teams alert successfully?

```
def sns_alert(object):
'''Sends SNS Teams alert failed to load object'''
try:
    message = f'{object} failed to load'
    subject = f'{object} failed to load'
    sc = boto3.client(service_name='sns')
    response = sc.publish(
    TopicArn = 'arn:MSTEAMS-SNS-TOPIC', 
    Message = json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(message)}),
    Subject = json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(subject)}),
    MessageStructure = 'json'
    
)
    return response
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Comment: Messages can be send to Microsoft Teams using Bot or Webhooks(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-a-message-through-incoming-webhook-or-office-365-connector). Can you please explain what you are using here?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I am attempting to send an SNS notification to MS Teams utilizing AWS Boto3 SNS service.

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html

Comment: There are different ways to send messages in MS Teams such as using [Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) or [Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-a-message-through-incoming-webhook-or-office-365-connector) or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I already have an SNS topic in AWS that is configured to send alerts to MS Teams. The issue is that whenever I try to use the Boto3 SNS function.. SNS is failing to send due to "invalid Subject"

Comment: Please refer this doc(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/) which explains how to send AWS SNS messages to MS Teams